# How can I display text on the back of my card in the correct writing direction?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter container that is toggled with a GestureDetector to switch between its front and back sides. The container is animated with the Transform method, rotating around the Y-axis to switch between the front and back sides.

The problem I have is that the text on the back side of the container is not properly aligned. The text appears mirrored. I have tried changing the textDirection property of the Text widget to align the text from right to left or left to right, but it didn't work.

Is there another way to properly align the text on the back of the container after it has been rotated?

Here is my current code:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FlipCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlipCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FlipCard> createState() => _FlipCardState();
}

class _FlipCardState extends State<FlipCard>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool _isFrontVisible = true;
  late AnimationController _flipAnimationController;
  late Animation<double> _flipAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _flipAnimationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    _flipAnimation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_flipAnimationController);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _flipAnimationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _toggleCard() {
    if (_isFrontVisible) {
      _flipAnimationController.forward();
    } else {
      _flipAnimationController.reverse();
    }
    _isFrontVisible = !_isFrontVisible;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => _toggleCard(),
          child: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _flipAnimation,
            builder: (context, child) {
              final value = _flipAnimation.value;
              final perspective = 0.002;
              final angle = value * pi;
              final isFrontFacing = angle <= pi / 2;
              return Transform(
                transform: Matrix4.identity()
                  ..setEntry(3, 2, perspective)
                  ..rotateY(angle),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 300,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: isFrontFacing ? Colors.white : Colors.blueGrey,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      isFrontFacing ? "Vorderseite" : "Rückseite",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: isFrontFacing ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                      ),
                      textDirection:
                          isFrontFacing ? TextDirection.rtl : TextDirection.ltr,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming the Text widget inside the card (for the "backside") is one possibility.

Below we've split the front & back cards into their own Widgets, then call either Widget depending on `isFrontFacing`.

```
class CardTextBack extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardTextBack();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        transform: Matrix4.rotationY(pi),
        child: const Text("Rückseite",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              color: Colors.white,
            )));
  }
}

class CardTextFront extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardTextFront();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Text("Vorderseite",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          color: Colors.black,
        ));
  }
}

class CardText extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardText(this.isFrontFacing);

  final bool isFrontFacing;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isFrontFacing) {
      return const CardTextFront();
    }
    return const CardTextBack();
  }
}
```

In your `_FlipCardState` we replace your final `child:` with:

```
child: Center(child: CardText(isFrontFacing)),
```